# When running the app in Tab error is coming

Tags: android

```
09-15 12:58:52.038: ERROR/dalvikvm-heap(26900): 6025950-byte external allocation too large for this process.
09-15 12:58:52.038: ERROR/GraphicsJNI(26900): VM won't let us allocate 6025950 bytes
09-15 12:58:52.042: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(26900): Shutting down VM
09-15 12:58:52.042: WARN/dalvikvm(26900): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d7d0)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.curl/com.android.curl.StandaloneExample}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.android.curl.PageCurlView
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:871)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:629)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class com.android.curl.PageCurlView
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:565)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:210)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at com.android.curl.StandaloneExample.onCreate(StandaloneExample.java:26)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     ... 11 more
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at com.android.curl.PageCurlView.<init>(PageCurlView.java:258)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     ... 21 more
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:590)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:564)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:425)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:448)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource(BitmapFactory.java:474)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     at com.android.curl.PageCurlView.init(PageCurlView.java:345)
09-15 12:58:52.062: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(26900):     ... 25 more
09-15 12:58:52.073: WARN/ActivityManager(2486):   Force finishing activity com.android.curl/.StandaloneExample
09-15 12:58:52.073: WARN/ActivityManager(2486):   Force finishing activity com.android.curl/.AndroidPageCurlActivity
```

here is my XMl

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/RootView">

     <com.android.curl.PageCurlView 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
     android:id="@+id/dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1" 
     android:background="@drawable/icon">
     </com.android.curl.PageCurlView>
     </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout

 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:id="@+id/RootView">
 
 
 <com.android.curl.PageCurlView
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/dcgpagecurlPageCurlView1"
  android:background="@drawable/icon">
 </com.android.curl.PageCurlView>
 
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: What line is line 11 in your XML? Thats where your error is.

Comment: This question is too vague to receive an answer. But http://developer.android.com/search.html#q=activity%20tab&t=0 may help to use activities in tabs.

Comment: @kaaku this error is due to the outof memory exception so try to avoid it by using less bitmap in view

Answer (score 1):

try to use smaller background image

```
android:background="@drawable/icon"
```

Answer (score 1):

Increase the amount of RAM as well as the VM Max Memory Heap size in your VM options. Go to Window-->AVD Manager-->Virtual Devices--->Edit, then click Add next to the list of specs at the bottom of the AVD profile.

Hope that helps!